# ReactJS Docker Nginx only displays Welcome to nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I am trying to run my ReactJS app in Docker with Nginx but when I run the docker image locally it on'y displays the general "Welcome to NGINX' home page.

**Dockfile**

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/bitnami/node:latest as build
# environment variables
ENV PORT='8080'
ENV ENVIRONMENT='dev'
ENV NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps && npm install react-scripts@3.3.0 -g --silent
COPY . /app
RUN react-scripts build

FROM public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/nginx:latest
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=build /app/build /var/www
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I also tried copying the contents to */usr/share/nginx/html* and setting that as root in the *nginx.conf* but same result.

***nginx.conf***

```
server {
    listen 80;
    root   /var/www;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;          
    }
}
```

I also have set the homepage property in *package.json*

```
  "homepage": "/",
```

Not sure if this is needed by this is what my *./src/App.js* file looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Auth from "./Pages/auth";
import Home from "./Pages/Home";
import NoMatch from "./Pages/NoMatch";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import blueprntTheme from "./Components/Theme";
import Launchpad from "./Pages/launchpad";

function App() {
  const [isLogIn, setIsLogIn] = useState(true);

  return (
    <Router>
      <ThemeProvider theme={blueprntTheme}>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            {/* TODO: Check error 4040 */}
            {/*
              !isLogIn ?
                <Route path='/' render={() => <Auth /> } />  
                :
                <Route path='/' render={() => <Home /> } />
            */}
            <Route path='/' render={() => <Auth />} />
            <Route path='/LaunchPad' render={() => <Launchpad />} />

            {/*<Route path='/' render={() => <Home /> } />*/}
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What command do you use to run the container? And are you sure there's an `index.html` file in the /var/www directory?

Comment: Not running it via the terminal. I am running the container using docker desktop. In the build directory there is an index.html. /app/build gets copied into /var/www. Should the root be /var/www/app/build?